# Мобильные игровые движки

Tags: разработка-игр

решил себя попробовать в разработке мобильных игр. Подскажите игровые движки, которыми вы пользуетесь и почему.

Языки программирования: Java/ C#. Рассматриваю как 2D, так и 3D движки.

Answer (score 0):

**Unity 3D**

1.Большое сообщество

2.Поддержка C#, JS

3.2D,3D

4.Куча встроенных сервисов(реклама,оплата и тд)

5.Огромное кол-во документации на ру/англ языках 6 и тд тд